# find out data which are inconsistent

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I have a two column data frame in R, let's say it is like the following

```
V1 V2
1 2
2 4
1 2
2 3
1 2
...
```

If the value in V1 appears more than once, and if these lines having the common V1 value have different V2 values, filter them out.

How can I do this efficiently in R? I think I need to use some hash functionality, right? But I am not sure how to do.

Thank you.

Comment: show us your code and expected output !

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Try this:

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), V2 = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L))

is.ok <- function(x) var(range(x)) == 0
subset(DF, ave(V2, V1, FUN = is.ok) == 1)
```

The result of the last line is:

```
  V1 V2
1  1  2
3  1  2
5  1  2
```

To get the inconsistent data rather than the consistent data then change `== 1` to `== 0` in the last code line.

**2)** If you prefer not showing duplicates then this displays the consistent rows but without duplicates:

```
subset(unique(DF), ave(V2, V1, FUN = length) == 1)
```

This gives:

```
  V1 V2
1  1  2
```

Change `== 1` to `> 1` in the code to instead show the inconsistent rows omitting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The use of indefinite pronouns in problem specification is prone to misinterpretation. I am showing code that interprets "them" as "all instances of rows where a value of V1 is associated with more than one value of V2" and where "filter" is intepreted as deliver them in a data.frame for examination.

```
  more.than.one.V2 <- dfrm[ave(dfrm$V2, dfrm$V1, 
                             FUN=function(x){length(unique(x))!=1} ), ]
  only.one.V2 <- dfrm[ave(dfrm$V2, dfrm$V1, 
                             FUN=function(x){length(unique(x))==1} ), ]
```